# NCover couldn't create a coverage report. 0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, ncover, ncover-explorer

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Professional with TestDriven.NET 2.14.2190, Windows XP (x86).

When i right click on my unit tests project, test with - Coverage, I obtain the following output:
NCover couldn't create a coverage report.

and the result:
0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped

I have no other versions of NCover installed, just the VS and TestDriven .NET

The actual testing is performed as expected - all tests successfully pass (so, there's nothing wrong with my class)

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did You put pdb-files beside the assembly files? Otherwise NCover won't work.